# Reusing aligned images for edge detection and thresholding

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Hi I am trying to implement focus stacking in python. I have looked at Photoshop and how it does the stacking of images and the results are exceptionally good. But I want to apply a similar technique using Python.

1. I have currently used ECC algorithm to align the images together
2. Done edge detection on them, dilated and blurred the images
3. Applied a threshold value to generate area of interest ( not sure about this step).
   And I am stuck here on how to proceed. In Photoshop, when we load a stack of images we use autoalign to align the images and then when we stack them together it creates masks of images using which it creates the sharp final image. 
   It would be really helpful if someone can review what I have done so far is in the right direction and if not guide me to it.

```
def stackImagesECC(file_list):
    M = np.eye(3, 3, dtype=np.float32)

    first_image = None
    stacked_image = None

    for file in file_list:
        image = cv2.imread(file,1).astype(np.float32) / 255
        print(file)
        if first_image is None:
            # convert to gray scale floating point image
            first_image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            stacked_image = image
        else:
            # Estimate perspective transform
            s, M = cv2.findTransformECC(cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), first_image, M, cv2.MOTION_HOMOGRAPHY)
            w, h, _ = image.shape
            # Align image to first image
            image = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (h, w))
            stacked_image += image

    stacked_image /= len(file_list)
    stacked_image = (stacked_image*255).astype(np.uint8)
    return stacked_image
```

This function aligns the images

```
images = glob.glob("edges_canny/*.jpg")
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
for image in images:
    with open(image, 'rb') as file:
        img = Image.open(file)
#         img.show()
        indexed = np.array(img)
        img_dilate = cv2.dilate(indexed, kernel, iterations=1)
        very_blurred = ndimage.gaussian_filter(img_dilate, sigma=5)
        ret, thresh5 = cv2.threshold(very_blurred, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_TOZERO_INV) 
        cv2.imshow("a",thresh5)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Here I am reading the edge detected images again and performing dilation, gaussian blur and thresholding on it to get areas of interest(which I am not sure about). I believe there is some way of directly reading aligned images from the alignment function.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. Furthermore, It does not seem to be a question within the scope of this forum per the help section.  https://stackoverflow.com/help.

Comment: @fmw42 what I am asking here is how to use the aligned images for edge detection and defining thresholds on those edge detected images to create masks.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know focus stacking. I do not expect people to learn that just to answer your question as you seem to hope. Perhaps someone who knows that technique can guide you. Otherwise, I suggest that you search Google and/or this forum for more details on focus stacking. But please read the help section of this forum for appropriate types of questions.

Comment: @fmw42 sorry but I didn't mean it to sound like that at all. I am trying to ask how to get the aligned images as an input for my edge detection rather than reading them separately from a folder. And then performing dilation and blurring on it.

Comment: `@Happy`. Perhaps I do not understand your question from your comment. But once you have done your ECC alignment, the images are available in Python for further use. You do not have to save them to disk. They are simply numpy arrays. Please clarify your question, if that is not what you are asking.

Comment: `@Happy. Perhaps it would help, if you edit your question to make it more clear what you are asking and where in your code it refers. From your comments, your question is not really about focus stacking. The title is misleading. But it more about re-use of your aligned images. Am I correct or do I still misunderstand?

Comment: @fmw42 yes you got it right. I'll edit my question as it is misleading. Sorry about that

Comment: @fmw42 you are correct I want to reuse the images aligned by using the function. Right now I am returning a final image which is the blended image after stacking them together. I just want to use the images that have been aligned. I am not sure if those images are in ```image```. Any suggestions?

Comment: @fmw42 How can I view those aligned images?

Comment: You can view them using cv2.imshow(). Perhaps I still do not understand, since you already use cv2.imshow()

Comment: @fmw42 I am asking are they in the image variable? Because I tried viewing them using cv2.imshow() and it showed the original images instead of the aligned images

Comment: Sorry, I am not following your code. Why do you not use opencv cv2.imread to read your images? Try viewing your img variable right after reading it. Does it display?  I suggest testing code in small increments to be sure each part is working properly.

Comment: @fmw42 yes i have tried that and it works. I am asking about the warped images after applying transformECC where it aligns them. I want to access those warped images.

Comment: Have you tried using cv2.imshow(...) in your stackImagesECC routine? You should also be able to use cv2.imshow(...) on your returned stacked_image in the main routine.

Comment: @fmw42 I tried it in the main routine and it only displays one picture which is a stacked image of all the warped image(final product).

Comment: Try it in the subroutine right after doing the perspective warp but before stacked_image. Label each one differently in cv2.imshow, say with some index number for each image. Does that work? Otherwise, I cannot help further. Python/OpenCV is not my area of expertise.

Comment: @fmw42 thanks for all the pointers. I'll try it in the sub-routine. I hope it works. Really appreciate your time.